# If a NVMe SSD has been used about 75%, will this effect it's write speed test?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, ssd, nvme, m.2

I have a NVMe SSD Kingston KC3000, PCIe 4.0. In Windows 10 it says 1.86 TB large, and I used about 75% of it, with 483 GB space left.

Recently when I boot my PC the first time everyday it always goes into bios and I can't find this SSD in the booting devices. Most of the time if I press F10 and restart again, it boot successfully into windows. I searched a lot and experimented, this is probably caused by the fact that the motherboard boot too fast, leaving not enough time for the SSD to get powered fully so the motherboard failed detecting the SSD. Right now there’s nothing I tried can solve this problem.

Anyway this made me to wonder if my SSD has some problem. So I use CrystalDiskMark to test it’s read and writing speed. For several times it varies a lot, and here are some screenshots:

[image]

Is it normal for an almost full SSD to have such low speed especially for writing? If not does the speed test mean my SSD will break soon? Thank you!

Comment: You may try disabling the Fast Boot feature (it may have different names depending on the manufacturer, please consult your user's manual). Also update UEFI, if available. It has nothing to do with the amount of free space, you're confusing several things here. Namely, *I can't find this SSD in the booting devices* is nonsensical in the context of UEFI boot process (unlike the old BIOS it doesn't boot from "devices", it boots from the EFI System Partition and that can even be in a different drive than the main OS or OSes partition(s)). You're very likely asking th WRONG question here.

Comment: Please post the S.M.A.R.T output by installing [smartmontools](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/Download#InstalltheWindowspackage) and either executing `smartctl -a /dev/<disk>` or if installing the context menu options, open Explorer [This PC], right-click on `C:`, choosing _SMART all info_

Comment: SSD not detected on boot, write speed vs used space, two entirely different issues. "noting I tried solves this problem" is too vague, you need to describe what was tried. IMO the questions needs focus on one issue and more details on solutions already tried.

Comment: @JW0914 - OP states "windows 10"

Comment: @JaromandaX I'm confused as to what you're referencing? The smartmontools link is for the Windows installer and when using it after installing, `smartctl -a /dev/<disk>` is still used within the custom terminal that opens when using smartmontools on Windows.

Comment: @JW0914 sorry, didn't realise smartmontools for windows did that